# Load datatable after filter other datatable

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables, master-detail

I have one datatable with the data of a table. I have other datatable and it's the child of the other one. When I click in a row of the parent datatable it will load the child datatable with the filtered rows. One example: I have in the parent table one provider with PK code 1. If I click in that row in the child table will appear all the articles of the provider 1. If I click in the provider 2 in the child table will appear all articles of the second provider.
I've done it but the problem is that the child datatable isn't load like that. It's load like a simple html table and not like a datatable.
I put here the code to load and catch the value of selected row, the js file with the ajax petition for refresh the child table and the php code for load the table.

**Load tables**

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    var oTable=$('#PRESUP').dataTable( {
        "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        "oTableTools": {
                "sRowSelect": "single"
        }
    } );
    oTable.$('tr').click( function () {
        var data = oTable.fnGetData( this );
        var serie=data[0];
        var numero=data[1];
        var nombre=data[3];
        var vendedor=data[4];
        $("#prueba1").val(serie); 
        $("#prueba2").val(numero);
        $("#seriedel1").val(serie);
        $("#numerodel1").val(numero);
        $("#nombre1").val(nombre);
        $("#vendedor1").val(vendedor);
        load();
        $("#eds").val(serie);
        $("#edn").val(numero);
      } );
    var oTable2=$('#PRESUP_D').dataTable( {
        "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        "oTableTools": {
            "sRowSelect": "single"
        }

    } );
    oTable2.$('tr').click( function () {
        var data = oTable.fnGetData( this );

      } );
} );
```

**AJAX**

```
function load()
{
    var serie=document.getElementById("prueba1").value;
    var numero=document.getElementById("prueba2").value;
    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){

        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else{

        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("PRESUP_D").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","mostralle.php",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("serie="+serie+"&numero="+numero);
}
```

**PHP**

```
include"conexion.php";
        $serie=$_POST['serie'];
        $numero=$_POST['numero'];
        mysql_connect($servidor, $usuario, $clave)or die    (mysql_errno().mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db($basedatos)or die (mysql_errno().mysql_error());
        $result=mysql_query("SELECT Serie, Numeroas, Numlinea, Codart, Cant, Descripcion, Precio, Tipoiva, Subtotal FROM PRESUP_D WHERE Serie='$serie' AND Numeroas='$numero'");
        while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result)){
            echo "<tr>";
            for($i=0;$i<mysql_num_fields($result);$i++){
                echo "<td>$row[$i]</td>";
            }
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        mysql_close();
```